# ng-message value for field without validation errors

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to set up a form field that will contain AngularJS validation through the ng-messages module using this simple example code:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" required minlength="5" />
    <div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="minlength">The value entered is too short</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to set up an "all criteria met" case, so that I can tie it to its own properly styled div and inform users that their entry meets all validation requirements? The API documentation doesn't mention it, nor do any other how-to guides or forum posts. It would be nice to have a ng-message keyword to represent an acceptable entry.

Comment: $valid expose this infromation!

Answer (score 1):

A field without validation errors is a `$valid` field. So use your `ng-show` with it.

```
<div ng-show="myForm.myField.$valid">Everything seems fine.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good exemple :

HTML

```
<div ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">  

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- FORM ============ -->

    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- VALIDATION TABLES ======== -->    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Form</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$valid, danger: userForm.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$pristine, danger: !userForm.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Name</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$valid, danger: userForm.name.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$pristine, danger: !userForm.name.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$touched }">Touched</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Username</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$valid, danger: userForm.username.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$pristine, danger: !userForm.username.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$touched }">Touched</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Email</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$valid, danger: userForm.email.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$pristine, danger: !userForm.email.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$touched }">Touched</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
// create angular app
    var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

    // create angular controller
    validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

        // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
        $scope.submitForm = function() {

            // check to make sure the form is completely valid
            if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
                alert('our form is amazing');
            }

        };

    });
```